# Accessing struct variables outside of function in C

Tags: c, variables, pointers, struct

I am having trouble understanding the scope of variables within a struct. For example:

```
struct Class 
{
const char *name;
int Hitdice, Str_Dice, Dex_Dice, Con_Dice, Int_dice, Wis_Dice, Cha_Dice, Skill_Points, level;
double BAB_Type;
struct Class *next_Class;
};

void setName()
{
struct Class setName;
setName.name = "thomas";
}

int main()
{

}
```

Is the variable *name only set to "thomas" within void setName()? How would I make it so that if I give a value to a struct variable that that value is accessible globally. If I was to print out the variable name within int main() it would be blank, how would I make it print out "thomas"? Or is that only doable within the function setName()?

Comment: The `struct` is the same as any other local variable.  You can't access local variables to a function from outside the function.

Comment: You will have to malloc the memory for "thomas" if you want your global struct to still point to it. I suggest returning the char* from the function in order to be able to free it later.

Comment: If you tried to print it out within `main()`, you'd get a compiler error, since the `setName` variable is only declared within the `setName()` function. It's not that `setName.name` is "unset" when the function exits, it's that the `setName` struct doesn't exist outside the function in which it's declared.

Comment: @LeatherFace What "global struct" do you see in the example?

Comment: He will have to declare a global structure then delete the local structure in the function.

Comment: Yes it is only "thomas" within the scope of setName(). If you wanted to access it from anywhere you would declare it before everything else with the scope modifier static.

Comment: Structures don't have variables but **fields**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the variable `name` only set to `"thomas"` within `void setName()`?

Yes. That's the essence of how local variables work

> How would I make it so that if I give a value to a struct variable that that value is accessible globally?

Make `struct Class setName;` global by declaring it *outside* `setName` function. I suggest also giving it a different name - say, `theClass`.

You should also change `setName` to take both the name and `struct Class` on which you would like to set the name.

> If I was to print out the variable name within int `main()` it would be blank, how would I make it print out `"thomas"`?

Once you move the declaration outside `setName()` function, you would be able to access it from anywhere you'd like.

```
struct Class {
    const char *name;
    int Hitdice, Str_Dice, Dex_Dice, Con_Dice, Int_dice, Wis_Dice, Cha_Dice, Skill_Points, level;
    double BAB_Type;
    struct Class *next_Class;
} theClass;

void setName(struct Class *myClass, const char* theName) {
    myClass->name = theName;
}

int main() {
    setName(&theClass, "thomas");
    printf("%s\n", theClass.name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, perfect explanation. 10/10.